# How to: multidimensional arrays in vhdl

Tags: arrays, vhdl

I'm trying to create a 5 dimensional array in VHDL but I'm unsure how I set and initialize the bits.

Here is what i have so far:

```
    type \1-line\ is array (4 - 1 downto 0) of unsigned (32 - 1 downto 0);
    type square is array (4 - 1 downto 0) of \1-line\;
    type cube is array (4 - 1 downto 0) of square;
    type hypercube is array (4 - 1 downto 0) of cube;
    type \5-cube\ is array (4 - 1 downto 0) of cube;

    signal mega_array : \5-cube\;
    begin
        process (clock, reset) begin
                if (reset == '1') then
                        mega_array <= '0';
                end if;
        end process;
    end behv;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A way to do it is with '(others =>'0')'.  This is a clean and safe way to set all bits of the vector at '0'.  You have to do this for every layer of your array.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity test is
    port (
        clock : in std_logic;
        reset : in std_logic);
end entity test;

architecture behv of test is

    type \1-line\ is array (4 - 1 downto 0) of unsigned (32 - 1 downto 0);
    type square is array (4 - 1 downto 0) of \1-line\;
    type cube is array (4 - 1 downto 0) of square;
    type \5-cube\ is array (4 - 1 downto 0) of cube;

    signal mega_array : \5-cube\;

begin

    process (clock, reset)
    begin
        if (reset = '1') then           -- note: not '=='
            mega_array <= (others => (others => (others => (others => (others => '0')))));
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture behv;
```

Note that although the `\1-...` naming is correct VHDL, I would not use it to avoid nasty tools issues.  I'm not sure they will come, but avoiding them is better then solving them.  I would use `t_1line` instead.

Comment: i just used a for loop to initialise them

Answer (score 1):

An aggregate is what you need:

`(others => '0')` sets all the bits in a vector to '0'

`(others => (others => '0'))` sets all the elements of an array of vectors to all bits '0'

`(others => (others => (others => '0')))`... etc. :)